# is it possible in sqlmap that multiple value for parameter in --data (post)

Tags: penetration-testing, sqlmap

I have to check multiple value for same post parameter.

Example : `matrix_id` is my parameter in `--data`.

I have the value `matrix_id=5896`,

I need to check like `matrix_id=5896,5893,5847,5893`. need to check all these specified values.

code will be **`sqlmap.py -u"myurl" --data"matrix_id=5896,5893,5847,5893" --dbs`**

Comment: The data in `--data` follow the `POST` request rules, so I don't think you can add a list of parameters in the way you wrote. But you could use bash with something like `sqlmap.py -u"myurl" --data"matrix_id={5896,5893,5847,5893}" --dbs` to sequentially test your app with all the different values.

Comment: @mrnfrancesco thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it by just separating the values with a comma.
And when you run SQLMap with multiple values in the --data parameter, it will test each value individually.

So if we go with your example you can just run your code as the way you put it ;

`sqlmap.py -u "myurl" --data "matrix_id=5896,5893,5847,5893" --dbs`

Hope this helps.